# How to create a parser which is a whitespace but not a line separator, in PetitParser?

Tags: whitespace, dart, petitparser

There is a built-in `whitespace()` parser in [PetitParserDart](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserDart), which checks character in:

```
(9 <= value && value <= 13) || (value == 32) || (value == 160)
  || (value == 5760) || (value == 6158) || (8192 <= value && value <= 8202) || (value == 8232)
  || (value == 8233) || (value == 8239) || (value == 8287) || (value == 12288)
```

Now I want a custom whitespace parser that is a `whitespace()` parser, but not accept line separator `\n`.

How to do that, I don't want to copy and modify the code inside `whitespace()`. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

One way that reuses the existing parser would be:

```dart
char('\n').not().seq(whitespace()).pick(1);
```

Another way is to create a new character pattern:

```dart
pattern('\t\f\r ');
```

This does not exactly match all the unicode whitespaces that `whitespace()` accepts, but likely is enough for most use-cases. Alternatively you can add the unicode ranges as well:

```dart
pattern('\t\f\r \u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000');
```